# Some CSS problems creating a theme from a psd file

Tags: html, css, themes, photoshop

I am studying how to create a tabless CSS web template starting from a PSD file and coding it into HTML + CSS but I am having some problem.

Befor explain my problem I show you my result (this is not the final result):

http://onofri.org/example/WebTemplate/

As you can see I have a problem into the header because the repeated background image of the body (bg.jpg) don't match well with the background immage of the #header div (bgheader.jpg).

The strange thing is that this problem only occurs in the blue area and not in the above gray shade; all match, the color of the top grey shade match but the blue zone don't match.

Regarding the repeated immage bg.jpg I took care to crop it so that it was contiguous to the bgheader.jpg

I can't understand what is the problem and how can I solve it because it seems to me to have  scrupulously followed the tutorial: http://www.html.it/articoli/da-photoshop-al-sito-xhtmlcss-7/

Infact the expected result in the tutorial is something like: http://www.html.it/articoli/1688/template/6-css.html

Here you can also dowload my psd file for my version of this template: http://onofri.org/example/WebTemplate/template4.psd

Someone can help me to solve?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: which browser do you use?

Comment: I have try with Firefox, Explorer and Chrome, I think that there is not a browser problem but some error that I have done...

Comment: Why not remove the background image of the header section? And then with the logo, just cut the logo out with a transparent background (I haven't looked at the PSD so not sure if it's possible). So that you don't need to try to align the logo's background with the body's background?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure of the problem you are facing. What do you mean by

> "As you can see I have a problem into the header"??

With my Firefox I don't see a apparent problem.
I could not see your pdf as-well (gives me a 404 Page Not Found error)

Please provide further explanation.

But some general observation:
 Its not a good idea to use the technique of repeating the background that includes separate colors of header, separator, body. Almost all the styling that the images have achieved for your webpage can be easily achieved by CSS3 (most modern browsers support them).

If you are good with PS you can anyway create your own gradients, else you can Check: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ (there are many more available).